# Legacy FBJS causing errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, legacy, fbjs

I'm having trouble with some old legacy FBJS. To validate the value of a field I was using

```
document.getElementById('email2').getValue()
```

This is now giving me the error

```
Error: a197943730232760_document.getElementById("email2") is null
```

I'm getting this for any other fields, getChecked() is also failing. I can't seem to find any other problems and this has only stopped working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this looks like a FBJS problem. Check you do actually have an element with the ID 'email2', from the sounds of that error message, your page doesn't have an 'email2' at all, which is why it can't get the value.

Comment: Abby, as I said this *was* working - and yes, the fields are there - and has only just stopped working without any notice.

Comment: Ok. What result do you get from console.log(document.getElementById('email2')); ?